# Word ranking using Bayes theorem

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining

I have problem with find ranking of words while computing multiple contents.

I'm splitting each words from the contents except stop words.

I have individual word counting with all contents, i.e total contents count=30, word$_1$ count=some $x$, word$_2$ count=some $y$ and so on.

We cannot consider word occurrence in separate content. Now we can find probability of word$_1$ with word$_2$, word$_3$, ..., word$_m$ using Bayes theorem.

How can we find it?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. What "multiple contents" are you referring to? Are these separate documents? Or separate corpi? It sounds like you're trying to implement a basic [Language Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model). Have you had a look at any of the literature?

Comment: Homework? If so, please add homework tag.

Comment: This was not homework. I was new for developing an application when I posted this. I solved this after analyzed and compared various Bayes Algorithms. Thanks all.